File transfer via Apache NiFi using transfer configuration from pgdb
I've the configuration for files in pg database, with information like file source, destination, file pattern and etc..
And I want to have a nifi process where I'll read configuration via db and then provide this information in attributes to the another processors which will transfer file from source to destination.
I have the following flow in Nifi:

ProcessorQueryDatabaseTableRecord. (Reading configuration from db like source + destination)
SplitRecord. Splitting data per configuration record.
EvaluateJsonPath. To fetch configuration into attributes.
And then I have a problem... I cant provide pattern/regexp to fetchFile processor, there is only path and filename (I dont know exact name).
To get exact filename by pattern I have to use listFile, but ListFile does not accept incoming connections.

Can someone recommend what kind of processors and flow I should use to transfer files dynamically based on db configuration?

Thank you in advance guys!

You have the option to use Getfile processor also, a suggestion is to use the DatabaseParameterProvider this way you can eliminate the three processors prior to FetchFile

Hello, 10x for answer. Unfortunately GetFile also does not accept incoming connections. I checked for DatabaseParameterProvider and the same needs im covering with SplitRecord +EvaluateJsonPath combination
